# Override template shell on linux system in Active Directory domain?

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

Is there an easy way to override the Samba "template shell = /bin/bash" setting on a per-user basis?

This is for Linux systems joined to an Active Directory domain.  Some users want /bin/bash.  Others including myself want /bin/zsh.  Is there some AD attribute I can set?

Anything I've found via googling seems hackish at best (writing a script to replace /bin/sh -- maintenance hassle).

A similar serverfault question [Override LDAP shell](/questions/133983) seems OpenLDAP-oriented (but if someone knows how to get it working with AD, please say so).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using winbind, you can do the following:

1. Install IDMU as Christoph suggested. If you have 2003 R2 or later, [the necessary RFC 2307 schema is already installed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto#Configure%20AD), so you can skip this step.
2. Add the following to smb.conf, per the [Samba wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory#Windows_2003_R2_Active_Directory):

   > ```
   > winbind nss info = rfc2307
   > ```

   Again, this is only going to work if you're using winbind. Restart it once you've made the change.
3. Set users' `loginShell` attribute in Active Directory. winbind will honor that setting on its next refresh.

Comment: I can verify that this works on RHEL 6.5. When `loginShell` is not set it just uses the template one which is what we wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a large number of Linux systems using AD, this may not be efficient, but for a small number of systems, the simplest way of doing this is to run the following on the Linux machine:

```
getent passwd ADUSER >> /etc/passwd
```

Then edit the corresponding line in /etc/passwd to reflect the preferred shell (or better yet, use sed to change the shell entry on the fly before appending to /etc/passwd).  IDMU, as others have suggested, is probably the most elegant solution for multiple hosts, but the above  example gets the job done if you're just looking to do this on a few systems.

Comment: Looking for this answer for a week now. Thanks @rvf.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Identity Management for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc782782(WS.10).aspx) (IDMU) on your AD server, the LDAP schema is extended for storing Unix attributes and you can set the login shell in the "Unix Attributes" tab of the (user) object properties.